# Why awk does not read 0 as a line in my script?

Tags: bash, if-statement, awk, mean

I have a problem with my awk script. It's main purpose is to take the sum of 2 following lines, calculate mean and than go to the next lines. I want my output to be one column of means.

The problem is when I have 0 (number) in the input. In such case awk somehow skips this line. So the output of this:

```
2
3
4
0
```

is this:

```
2.5
```

I want it to work like this:

input example:

```
2
3
6
7
```

output example:

```
2.5
6.5
```

My awk script looks like this:

```
BEGIN { x = 0}
$0 {
    x = x + 1 
    sum += $0
    if ( x == 2 ) {
        print sum/x
        x = 0
        sum = 0
    }
}
```

How can I make this work?

Thx

Comment: The string "0" evaluates to false, so the rule "$0" evaluates to false.  If you want to check that the string is not empty, evaluate the length of the string rather than its truthity.

Comment: You already got your question answered but beyond that, consider coding it this way: `awk -v n=2 '{sum+=$0} !(NR%n){print sum/n; sum=0}' file`.

Comment: try to remove the leading $0 at line 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with using `$0` alone as a condition. This will be false if the value is an empty string or the number `0`.

Change that to `$0 != ""` so you just compare it with the string. Or use `NF` to check if there is at least 1 field in the row.

Answer (score 0):

using any awk:

```
awk '
{x+=$1;y++} # increment x by value of $1; increment y by 1
{if (y==2) print x/y} # if y equal 2 print x div y
{y==2 && (x="0") && (y="0")} # if operand is true, moves to next (right)
' input.txt
```